# Date changes to next day Impala

Tags: impala, to-timestamp

I have a ‘Response_Date ‘ column that has VARCHAR datatype. This shows eastern time. The date is 3/31/2023 22:30. I am needing to change the format to date 3/31/2023 12:00:00 AM. When I use to_timestamp(Response_Date,’yyyy-MM-dd) as RES_DT, the date becomes 04/01/2023 12:00:00 AM. This is Impala environment. How do I get the March date instead of April?

When I use
to_timestamp(Response_Date,’yyyy-MM-dd') as RES_DT,
the date becomes 04/01/2023 12:00:00 AM. (I am expecting 03/31/2023 12:00:00 AM)
I am also creating a new column 'Month_Of' off of the response date. I am expecting 03/01/2023 12:00:00 AM but it gives me 04/01/2023 12:00:00 AM
Trunc(to_timestamp(Response_Date,’yyyy-MM-dd'), 'month') as Month_of

How do I get the March date instead of April?

Answer (score 0):

can you pls try

```
to_timestamp(split_part(Response_Date,' ',1),'MM/dd/yyyy') as Response_Date_truncated
```

i think to_timestamp is trying to convert to a timestamp considering the time. Remove the time part using `split_part()` and i think you should be good.

Comment: Thank you Kaushik.So I am using to_timestamp and split_part? It is giving me null values.